# Scala return prime numbers from Array

Tags: scala, primes

I'm quite new to Scala so apologies for the very basic question.

I have this great on liner that checks if a number is a prime. What I'm trying to do with it is allowing the function to take in an Array and spit out the out the prime numbers.

How can I best achieve this? Is it possible to do so in a one liner as well? Thanks!

```
def isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = (2 to num) forall (x => num % x != 0)
```

Comment: Look into `filter`  function.

Comment: `math.ceil(math.sqrt(num)).toInt` should be enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I'm trying to do with it is allowing the function to take in an Array and spit out the out the prime numbers

You can do the following

```
def primeNumbs(numbers: Array[Int]) = numbers.filter(x => !((2 until x-1) exists (x % _ == 0)) && x > 1)
```

and if you pass in array of numbers as

```
println(primeNumbs(Array(1,2,3,6,7,10,11)).toList)
```

You should be getting

```
List(2, 3, 7, 11)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Note:** your `isPrime` function doesn't work

Comment: Note: your primality test doesn't work either. It returns `0 -> true`,
`1 -> true`. How many broken implementations of `isPrime` can we get for one single question? ;)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, thanks for pointing that out :) now the update should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
def isPrime(num : Int) : Boolean = {
       ((1 to num).filter(e => (num % e == 0)).size) == 2
}
isPrime: (num: Int)Boolean

scala> (1 to 100) filter(isPrime(_)) foreach(e=> print(e+" "))
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isPrime` seems completely broken.

Even if you replace `to` by `until`, it will still return strange results for `0` and `1`.

Here is a very simple implementation that returns the correct results for `0` and `1`, and checks only divisors smaller than (approximately) `sqrt(n)` instead of `n`:

```
def isPrime(n: Int) = 
  n == 2 || 
  (n > 1 && (2 to (math.sqrt(n).toInt + 1)).forall(n % _ > 0))
```

Now you can `filter` primes from a range (or a list):

```
(0 to 10000).filter(isPrime).foreach(println)
```

You could also write it like this:

```
0 to 10000 filter isPrime foreach println
```

But this version with explicit lambdas probably generalizes better, even though it's not necessary in this particular case:

```
(0 to 10000).filter(n => isPrime(n)).foreach(n => println(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

In understand that the prime function may be the objective of your assignment/task/interest, but note that's already available in the JVM as `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`. With that, and the fact that Scala can call Java transparently, try the following `filter`:

```
import java.math.BigInteger
val r = (1 to 100).filter { BigInteger.valueOf(_).isProbablePrime(25) }.mkString(", ")
// "2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97"
```

This works by iterating the range of numbers (or your Array, or any `TraversableOnce`, same syntax) and letting pass only those numbers "`_`" in the closure that fulfill the condition, i.e. that are prime. And instead of *folding* with a string concatenation, there's a convenient helper `mkString` that inserts a separator into a sequence and produces a String for you.

And don't worry about the "probable" prime here. For such small numbers like here, there's no *probability* involved, despite the method name. That kicks in for numbers with maybe 30+ digits or so.

Comment: This may be right answer... bit explanation is good for better understanding : Review